# Why does a PHP variable containing a string move outside of the div?

Tags: php, html, css

So I have a template which I populate using PHP variables like so:

```
<p>'.$myVar.'</p>
```

Works perfectly except for that the var containing a string for some reason moves outside of the parent div. If I replace the variable with static text like so

```
<p>A lot of nice text etc. etc.</p>
```

this does not happen. I'm pretty sure this is not a CSS issue.

**EDIT**
The content of the var is:

```
$myVar = 'AFDKAAGKAGGAMAGKGASKGASKLNANÖLASDNASFDNAFSDNÖADSNLNLKFDSNKAFDSNKFASDLNÖAFSÖNLAFSLNÖKAFSDLNÖAFSDNÖLKSFADÖKNLDFSAÖNKLANKLFSADNÖFASDLNÖKFSNLÖKAFLNÖKFADSKLNÖFADSKLNÖFDSALKNÖFSDANLNLÖKNÖK';
```

Comment: Where is the div ? Can we see more code ? And the exact string ?

Comment: Does `$myVar` contain unescaped HTML?

Comment: Does the string contain any HTML? I hope, that I don't need to mention, what a security this may be...

Comment: Whats the content of the var? Does it perhaps contain HTML code that isn't properly escaped?

Comment: The var does not contain any additional HTML. It is only a string which is exactly: AFDKAAGKAGGAMAGKGASKGASKLNANÖLASDNASFDNAFSDNÖADSNLNLKFDSNKAFDSNKFASDLNÖAFSÖNLAFSLNÖKAFSDLNÖAFSDNÖLKSFADÖKNLDFSAÖNKLANKLFSADNÖFASDLNÖKFSNLÖKAFLNÖKFADSKLNÖFADSKLNÖFDSALKNÖFSDANLNLÖKNÖK

Comment: It even goes outside the comment column... Add some space if you want it to fit somewhere.

Comment: Right! Thanks for that. Didn't realize it was actually one word! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only one word, the HTML renderer won't be able to cut your text into multiple line. You will end up with an overflow. Force the word wrap:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 3):

A long string without any breaking space breaks most layouts, as you can see in the comments column.

Add a space in your string, or set in your css either the `overflow: hidden;` to hide the exceeding characters or `word-wrap: break-word;` to split the word in different lines.